# Chrome extension; how to get the location of dragged paragraph or text?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am a programming beginner, and I try to make a Chrome extension using javascript.

When I drag a paragraph or text in a webpage, can I get its location?

For example if I dragged second p tag paragraph, the second p tag becomes the location.

How can I get the return value like the second p tag?

Thank you for your reply in advance.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for fast reply! The location does not mean the coordinate or mouse cursor position. For example, in a webpage, there are a lot of p-tags, so if I dragged a paragraph, I would like to know exactly which order or p-tag from the top.

Comment: Assuming you already have an event listener and `event.target` points to the paragraph, see [Get child node index](//stackoverflow.com/a/39395069)

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks! I will check this:)